# Unable to import custom VMDK into Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to import a Red Hat 6 VMDK into Google Cloud. The documentation is straightforward and it appears to be working up until it is attempting to resize a "temp translation disk".

Specifically, is a Red Hat 6 VMDK Distribution, which is 64GB and is hosted in Google Cloud Storage. The account is a paid account and is also not on a trial basis, so if there were any trial restrictions, they shouldn't be there at this point.

Here is the command I run:

```sh
gcloud compute images import mshprs --source-file gs://mbucket/MY-VM-DISK.vmdk --os rhel-6
```

The VM is copied, as expected, to the Google Cloud project instance and then I get the following error:

```sh
Daisy] Errors in one or more workflows:
  import-and-translate: step "import" run error: step "wait-for-signal" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-nq26b": "ImportFailed: Failed to resize temp-translation-disk-nq26b to 237GB in projects/71352554514/zones/us-central1-f'"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/daisy:release" failed: exit status 1
```

I have not been able to get past this step even if after attempting to allocate it to different regions or simply try again.